# How to convert ArrayList into string array(string[]) in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, arraylist, type-conversion

How can I convert `ArrayList` into `string[]` in C#?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
string[] myArray = (string[])myarrayList.ToArray(typeof(string));
```

Comment: i tried this.i am getting following error on this        "At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type"

Comment: I know this is very late, but the reason you are getting that error is because the you probably have an ArrayList with elements that aren't strings too, and you are trying to cast the elements to string, which doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 4):

use [.ToArray(Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcyyh2hb.aspx)

```
string[] stringArray = (string[])arrayList.ToArray(typeof(string));
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple Google or search on MSDN would have done it. Here:

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList(); 

// Add stuff to the ArrayList.
String[] myArr = (String[]) myAL.ToArray( typeof( string ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```ccharp
using System.Linq;

public static string[] Convert(this ArrayList items)
{
    return items == null
        ? null
        : items.Cast<object>()
            .Select(x => x == null ? null : x.ToString())
            .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: i tried this.but i am getting following error                                            Error 'System.Collections.ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to include `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file. Also I was missing a `.Cast<object>()` call.

Comment: Dude! My fault. I actually thought this was good and hurridly pressed the wrong button! Now it's +1!

Answer (score 2):

Try do that with `ToArray()` method.

```
ArrayList a= new ArrayList(); //your ArrayList object
var array=(String[])a.ToArray(typeof(string)); // your array!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CopyTo method of ArrayList object.

Let's say that we have an arraylist, which has String Type as Elements.

```
strArrayList.CopyTo(strArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is as follows.

```
System.Collections.ArrayList al = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
al.Add("1");
al.Add("2");
al.Add("3");
string[] asArr = new string[al.Count];
al.CopyTo(asArr);
```