# how can i convert arraylist to string[]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert ArrayList into string array(string[]) in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924869/convert-arraylist-into-string-arraystring-in-c-sharp)

How can I convert array list to `string[]`?below is code I am trying. I am getting an error:

> At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type.

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
foreach (DataRow dtRow in DtSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    myArrayList.Add(dtRow);
}

string[] myStringArray = (string[])myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(string));
```

Comment: Are you still using .NET 1.1. or why don't you use typed `List<T>` instead of an `ArrayList`?

Comment: "At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type." it really is telling you the problem here... kind-of; every "element in the source array" is a `DataRow`. It is telling you it can't cast a `DataRow` to a `string`. Which is entirely correct; a `DataRow` **is not** a `string`...

Comment: You are trying to cast DataRows into strings. You need to first check if that is permissible with the rows that you have. If it is, you can simply loop through and case them individually and add it to string array. But I doubt this cast would succeed.

Comment: @Shaks: DataRows are **never** strings and can never be casted to string meaningfully. `DateRow.ToString()` would call `Object.ToString()` which is implemented as  `this.GetType().ToString()`. What you can do is cast every field in every datarow to string and join these fields.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I guess that's what is needed. :)

Comment: @Shaks: Yes, as i've done in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11501614/284240). by the way, this is not a duplicate from the other, only the misleading title is a dup. The other answer will OP not help at all to solve his issue.

Answer (score 5):

Are you still using .NET 1.1. or why don't you use typed `List<T>` instead of an `ArrayList`?

First, you cannot cast a `DataRow` to `String`. You can cast [every field of a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx) to a string.

If you can use [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) you can use following code to get a `String[]` of all row fields where each field is separated by comma:

```
String[] rowFields = DtSet.Tables[0]
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(r => string.Join(",", r.ItemArray));
                    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are placing a number of `DataRow` objects into an `ArrayList`. `DataRow`s are not `string`s. So: that can't work. At best, you can perhaps get the `.ToString()`, but frankly, that isn't going to be all that helpful - because every row will just say `System.Data.DataRow` (since it doesn't override `ToString()`. I think you need to re-evaluate what you are trying to do.

Example based on comment discussion:

```
DataTable table = ...
string[] strings = new string[table.Rows.Count];
int idx = 0;
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    object[] cells = row.ItemArray;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < cells.Length ; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0) sb.Append(',');
        sb.Append('"').Append(cells[i]).Append('"');
    }
    strings[idx++] = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i have one dataset and i need to pass values as string array[] to one method,how can i do that?converting dataset to string[]?

Comment: @user1527989 well, what do you expect a `DataRow` to *look like* as a string? For example, a `DataRow` with 5 cells, `{1,"abc",2.0,true,-12}` - what should that look like as a string?

Comment: @user1527989 but **what** string? what would it be? I've given you a row of sample data: how would you want that to appear, as a string?

Comment: "xyx@gmail.com","aaddcc@gmail.com","ddd@gmail.com" like this i want

Comment: @user1527989 k; next step: write some code that *does that*. See edit for example.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot take a DataRow (type) and add it to an ArrayList expecting it to be a string.
A DataRow is an object that has a myriad of information about the object as well as the objects data.

```
foreach(DataRow dtRow in dtSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    myArrayList.Add(dtRow["UserName"].ToString());
}

string[] myArray = myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(string));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an `ArrayList` whose elements are of type `DataRow`. You are trying to convert it into an array of `string`s. A `DataRow` is not a `string` (nor does it become one on downcasting), so you can't do that.

If the array of strings is what you ultimately want, you should probably call `ToString` (or whatever conversion you need) on each element while filling the `ArrayList`.

(Also, as Tim Schmelter said in comments, you should really be using a `List<T>` for some `T` -- probably either `string` or `DataRow`, depending on exactly how your code ends up looking -- rather than an `ArrayList`.)

Answer (score 1):

Each item the arrayList is of type DataRow, you can't cast it to a string.

Instead, you should construct a string that represents the contents of the row, and add that string to the list, e.g.

```
myArrayList.Add(dtRow["CustomerName"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
string[] array = myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
```

Comment: That will error in exactly the same way. `ArrayList` already returns a right-typed array, **when** it completes the `ToArray` method - which isn't happening here.

Comment: @user1527989 10 minutes ago, myself, Gareth, Dane etc told you pretty clearly that what you are trying to do **cannot** work, and exactly why. Why are you still trying to do that, rather than address the fundamental issue: a `DataRow` **is not a string** ?

Comment: My bad, should have read the question fully. @Marc is correct, you're adding `DataRows` to your arraylist and then trying to cast them to `string` which is not possible. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: humm ok gareth.i got the problem.thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

myArrayList.Add("as");
myArrayList.Add("as");
myArrayList.Add("as");
myArrayList.Add("as");
myArrayList.Add("as");            
myArrayList.Add("as");

string[] array = myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
foreach (var item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());                
}
```

Output:

```
as
as
as
as
as
as
```

Comment: While this is accurate as a standalone example, it does not address the context of the question, which specifically concerns `DataRow`.